# How to quantify rollback events in SQL Server between 2 dates

Tags: sql-server, performance, rollback

I need to quantify rollback events and find theirs reasons, without change the application code. There is any way to collect this data?

The reason to check the rollback occurrences have need to identify whether the change of configuration in my jboss datasource from local-tx transaction system to no-tx will impact the batch executions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As originally supplied by [Mark Sinkinson](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/33638/mark-sinkinson) in a question comment, the answer was found in:

[Identifying rolled back transactions](https://sqlscope.wordpress.com/2012/04/09/identifying-rolled-back-transactions/) by [SQLscope](https://sqlscope.wordpress.com/author/sqlscope/)

From that link:

> In SQL 2008 R2 and before there are very few ways to identify transactions that have been rolled back. A server side trace capturing the SQLTransaction events is one way. You’d filter on EventSubClass = 2 to capture just the rollbacks. Or you could try reading the transaction log using fn_dblog() filtering on Operation = LOP_ABORT_XACT. Yet another way, which provides very limited data, is to periodically query the syscacheobjects sql column for any text which is like ‘%rollback%’. Each of these methods has their own issues and overheads. Ideally we’d like a light-weight solution.
>
> Fortunately, in SQL Server 2012 extended events comes to the rescue. You can either use extended events to map to a trace definition for SQLTransaction events or you could roll your own event session. Here’s one possible roll your own solution:
>
> ```
> -- Create the event session to catch rollbacks
>
> CREATE EVENT SESSION evtsRollback
> ON SERVER
> ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_transaction (
>   ACTION (sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.database_id,sqlserver.sql_text)    -- Could add more actions
>   WHERE transaction_state = 2                        -- Rollbacks only
>   AND sqlserver.database_id = 8                        -- Just this one database
> )
> ADD TARGET package0.ring_buffer;
> GO
>
> -- Start the sesssion
> ALTER EVENT SESSION evtsRollback ON SERVER STATE=START;
>
> -- Begin a transaction, make a change, then rollback the transaction
>
> -- Drop the event
> ALTER EVENT SESSION evtsRollback ON SERVER DROP EVENT sqlserver.sql_transaction;
>
> -- Query the results
> SELECT
>   event.value('(event/@name)[1]','varchar(50)') AS event,
>   DATEADD(hh,DATEDIFF(hh,GETUTCDATE(),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),event.value('(event/@timestamp)[1]','datetime2')) AS [timestamp],
>   event.value('(event/action[@name="session_id"])[1]','int') AS session_id,
>   event.value('(event/action[@name="database_id"])[1]','int') AS database_id,
>   event.value('(event/data[@name="duration"])[1]','bigint') AS duration_microseconds,
>   event.value('(event/data[@name="transaction_id"])[1]','bigint') AS transaction_id,
>   event.value('(event/data[@name="transaction_state"]/text)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS transaction_state,
>   event.value('(event/data[@name="transaction_type"]/text)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS transaction_type,
>   event.value('(event/action[@name="sql_text"])[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS sql_text
> FROM
> (
>   SELECT n.query('.') AS event
>   FROM
>   (
>     SELECT CAST(target_data as XML) AS target_data
>     FROM sys.dm_xe_sessions AS s
>     JOIN sys.dm_xe_session_targets AS t
>     ON s.address = t.event_session_address
>     WHERE s.name = 'evtsRollback'
>     AND t.target_name = 'ring_buffer'
>   ) AS s
> CROSS APPLY target_data.nodes('RingBufferTarget/event') AS q(n)
> ) AS t;
>
> -- Tidy up
> DROP EVENT SESSION evtsRollback ON SERVER;
> ```